# Uppercase vs Lowercase

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a simple problem.

I have multiple ways to get a JSON from other apps that i dont control. All the keys have the same name but some are uppercase and some are lowercase.

How do I read the JSON so it doesn't matter if it's lowercase or uppercase?

For example in my code when the json has `customer_id` in lowercase it does not work

HTML

```
 <td ng-repeat="customer in customers">{{customer.CUSTOMER_ID}}</td> // this only works when the JSON keys comes uppercase
```

controller

```
// Get Customers
promises.customers.$promise.then(function (data) {
    $scope.customers = data["Customers"].Customers;

    if(!angular.isArray($scope.customers)) {
        $scope.customers = [$scope.customers];
    }
    console.log($scope.customers);
}.bind(this));
```

Comment: can you add that `JSON` here ?

Comment: I really wish you didn't name an object `promises` when it is not an array of promises. It makes for confusing code. `promise.customers` appears to be a RESTful $resource instance.

Answer (score 1):

You may normalize properties to be all in uppercase or lowercase:

```js
// Customers with a sample customer as provided in some comment by the OP
const customers = [{
    "account_id": 1,
    "account_type_description": "Single Account",
    "customer_id": 1,
    "first_name": "Peter",
    "last_name": "Parker",
    "identity_card_number": 128,
    "tax_identification": 35,
    "birth_date": "2018-06-28T07:57:23Z",
    "customer_gender_description": "Male",
    "street_address": "Gotham Street 56",
    "postal_code": "21312",
    "city": "Gotham",
    "country_description": "Portugal"
  },
  {
    "ACCOUNT_ID": 1,
    "ACCOUNT_TYPE_DESCRIPTION": "Single Account",
    "CUSTOMER_ID": 1,
    "FIRST_NAME": "Peter",
    "LAST_NAME": "Parker",
    "IDENTITY_CARD_NUMBER": 128,
    "TAX_IDENTIFICATION": 35,
    "BIRTH_DATE": "2018-06-28T07:57:23Z",
    "CUSTOMER_GENDER_DESCRIPTION": "Male",
    "STREET_ADDRESS": "Gotham Street 56",
    "POSTAL_CODE": "21312",
    "CITY": "Gotham",
    "COUNTRY_DESCRIPTION": "Portugal"
  }
]

const normalizeProperties = entities => entities.map(customer => {
  const outputCustomer = {}

  for (let property of Object.keys(customer))
    outputCustomer[property.toLowerCase()] = customer[property]

  return outputCustomer
})

const normalizedCustomers = normalizeProperties(customers)

console.log(JSON.stringify(normalizedCustomers))
```

There're many approaches to get the same result, but the idea is that you don't want those differences once you bind the model to the UI.

Comment: @user9999443 Obviously, if your binding is `customer.PROPERTY_IN_UPPERCASE`, it won't work... Just change my snippet where I do `property.toLowerCase()` to `property.toUpperCase()`...

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with the properties normalization, i.e with lodash you can use [`mapKeys`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#mapKeys):

```
const input = { CUSTOMER_ID: 1, name: 'foo' };
const normalized = _.mapKeys(input, (value, key) => key.toLowerCase());

// {customer_id: 1, name: "foo"}

console.log(normalized.customer_id); // 1
```

If the properties may be written as camelCase, you can normalize also those with  [`snakeCase`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#snakeCase):

```
const input = { CUSTOMER_ID: 1, otherId: 3, name: 'foo' };
const normalized = _.mapKeys(input, (value, key) => _.snakeCase(key));

// {customer_id: 1, other_id: 5, name: "foo"}

console.log(normalized.other_id); // 5
```

Comment: I cannot use external scripts ( this is a enterprise app). TypeError: _.mapKeys is not a function

Comment: @user9999443 This was an example. You can implement it in your own.

Answer (score 0):

To ignore case for all keys in the JSON, you can define a custom getter for the object like below

```
Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, "getProp", {
    value: function (prop) {
        var key,self = this;
        for (key in self) {
            if (key.toLowerCase() == prop.toLowerCase()) {
                return self[key];
            }
        }
    },
    enumerable: false
});
```

Now you can get properties ignoring the case like this

```
obj.getProp("CUSTOMER_ID");
//or
obj.getProp("customer_id");
```

Answer (score 0):

You could implement your own parsing function and call it on all JSON responses to normalise them.

E.g. Function to normalise all keys to lower case

```
function getParsedObjectWithUpperCaseKeys(jsonObject) {
    var parsedObjectWithUpperCaseKeys = {};

    Object.keys(jsonObject).forEach(function (jsonObjectKey) {
        parsedObjectWithUpperCaseKeys [jsonObjectKey.toUpperCase()] = jsonObject[jsonObjectKey];
    });

    return parsedObjectWithUpperCaseKeys;
}
```

And in your controller code:

```
// Get Customers
promises.customers.$promise.then(function (data) {
    var customers = data["Customers"].Customers;

    $scope.customers = getParsedObjectWithUpperCaseKeys(customers);

    if(!angular.isArray($scope.customers)) {
        $scope.customers = [getParsedObjectWithUpperCaseKeys(customers)];
    } else {
        $scope.customers = [getParsedObjectWithUpperCaseKeys(customers[0])];
    }
    console.log($scope.customers);
}.bind(this));
```

Comment: your code doesn't work for thi JSON `[
  {
    "account_id": 1,
    "account_type_description": "Single Account",
    "customer_id": 1,
    "first_name": "Peter",
    "last_name": "Parker",
    "identity_card_number": 2132142131,
    "tax_identification": 2892031231,
    "birth_date": "2018-06-28T07:57:23Z",
    "customer_gender_description": "Male",
    "street_address": "Gotham Street 56",
    "postal_code": "21312",
    "city": "Gotham",
    "country_description": "Portugal"
  }
]`

Comment: I want to convert to uppercase