# Convert Keys to Uppercase

Tags: javascript

I have a simple problem.

I have multiple ways to get a JSON from other apps that i dont control. All the keys have the same name but some are uppercase and some are lowercase.

How do I read the JSON so it doesn't matter if it's lowercase or uppercase?

For example in my code when the json has `customer_id` in lowercase it does not work

**My current function doesn't work. I need a generic function that convert the keys of a json object that can have 1 or more length to UPPERCASE**

HTML

```
 <td ng-repeat="customer in customers">{{customer.CUSTOMER_ID}}</td> // this only works when the JSON keys comes uppercase
```

controller

```
 //another function
 $http.get(baseUrl + param).then(function (response) {
        console.log(response.data.items);
        console.log(normalizeJSON(response.data.items));
        $scope.customers = normalizeJSON(response.data.items);
    });
};

function normalizeJSON (jsonObject) {
    var parsedObjectWithLowerCaseKeys = {};

    for(var i = 0; i < jsonObject.length; i++) {
        Object.keys(jsonObject[i]).forEach(function (itemKey) {
            parsedObjectWithLowerCaseKeys[itemKey.toUpperCase()] = jsonObject[itemKey];
        });

        return parsedObjectWithLowerCaseKeys;
    }
}
```

`response.data.items` gives

```
[
  {
    "account_id": 4,
    "account_type_description": "Joint Account",
    "customer_id": 4,
    "first_name": "Clark",
    "last_name": "Kent",
    "identity_card_number": 2132142134,
    "tax_identification": 2892031234,
    "birth_date": "2018-06-28T07:57:23Z",
    "customer_gender_description": "Male",
    "street_address": "Gotham Street 56",
    "postal_code": "21312",
    "city": "Gotham",
    "country_description": "Portugal"
  },
  {
    "account_id": 4,
    "account_type_description": "Joint Account",
    "customer_id": 5,
    "first_name": "Cristiano",
    "last_name": "Ronaldo",
    "identity_card_number": 2132142135,
    "tax_identification": 2892031235,
    "birth_date": "2018-06-28T07:57:23Z",
    "customer_gender_description": "Male",
    "street_address": "Gotham Street 56",
    "postal_code": "21312",
    "city": "Gotham",
    "country_description": "Portugal"
  }
]
```

EDIT: IT IS DIFFERENT

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Uppercase vs Lowercase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51081010/uppercase-vs-lowercase)

Comment: Fine exmaple would be: [`Convert JSON Keys to lowercase`](https://gist.github.com/radutta/4480e8292372da56b426f7a4c65f8774) and just invert the functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Update your function as below.

```
function normalizeJSON (jsonObject) {
    var newJsonObject = [];

    for(var i = 0; i < jsonObject.length; i++) {
        var parsedObjectWithLowerCaseKeys = {};
        Object.keys(jsonObject[i]).forEach(function (itemKey) {
            parsedObjectWithLowerCaseKeys[itemKey.toUpperCase()] = jsonObject[i][itemKey];
        });
        newJsonObject.push(parsedObjectWithLowerCaseKeys);
    }
    return newJsonObject;
}
```